# Using terminaltables, how can I get all my data in a single table, rather than split across multiple tables?

Tags: python, prettytable

I’m having a problem printing a table with terminaltables.

Here's my main script:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
from terminaltables import AsciiTable

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('my.conf')

for section_name in parser.sections():
    description = parser.get(section_name,'description')
    url = parser.get(section_name,'url')
    table_data = [['Repository', 'Url', 'Description'], [section_name, url, description]]
    table = AsciiTable(table_data)
    print table.table
```

and here's the configuration file `my.conf`:

```
[bug_tracker]
description = some text here
url = http://localhost.tld:8080/bugs/ 
username = dhellmann
password = SECRET

[wiki] 
description = foo bar bla
url = http://localhost.tld:8080/wiki/
username = dhellmann
password = SECRET
```

This print me a table for each entry like this:

```
+-------------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
| Repository  | Url                             | Description            |
+-------------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
| bug_tracker | http://localhost.foo:8080/bugs/ | some text here         |
+-------------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
+------------+---------------------------------+-------------+
| Repository | Url                             | Description |
+------------+---------------------------------+-------------+
| wiki       | http://localhost.foo:8080/wiki/ | foo bar bla |
+------------+---------------------------------+-------------+
```

but what I want is this:

```
+-------------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
| Repository  | Url                             | Description            |
+-------------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
| bug_tracker | http://localhost.foo:8080/bugs/ | some text here         |
+-------------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
| wiki        | http://localhost.foo:8080/wiki/ | foo bar bla            |
+-------------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
```

How can I modify the script to get this output?

Comment: You're creating a new table each time, you want to parse the section data for each entry and THEN create that single table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you recreate `table_data` and `table` on each iteration of the loop. You print on each iteration, and then the old data gets thrown away and a new table gets started from scratch. There’s no overlap in the body of the tables you’re creating.

You should have a single `table_data`, which starts with the headings, then you gather all the table data *before* printing anything. Add the new entries on each iteration of the loop, and put the print statement after the for loop is finished. Here’s an example:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
from terminaltables import AsciiTable

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('my.conf')

table_data = [['Repository', 'Url', 'Description']]

for section_name in parser.sections():
    description = parser.get(section_name,'description')
    url = parser.get(section_name,'url')
    table_data.append([section_name, url, description])

table = AsciiTable(table_data)
print table.table
```

and here’s what it outputs:

```
+-------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
| Repository  | Url                             | Description    |
+-------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
| bug_tracker | http://localhost.tld:8080/bugs/ | some text here |
| wiki        | http://localhost.tld:8080/wiki/ | foo bar bla    |
+-------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
```

If you want to have a horizontal rule between the bug_tracker and wiki lines, then you need to set `table.inner_row_border` to True. So you’d replace the last two lines with:

```
table = AsciiTable(table_data)
table.inner_row_border = True
print table.table
```